# C# Rad Desktop Alert - Show correct name

Tags: c#, alert, desktop, rad

I am writting a rad desktop alert for my CRM system, I have the people I want to call back inside a gridview, where a column holds the call back date and time. This is the full code so far:

```
public async void ScheduleAction(Action action, DateTime ExecutionTime)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now < ExecutionTime)//ExecutionTime - not passed
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
                action();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    public void action()
    {
        radDesktopAlert1.CaptionText = "Telefonmøde";
        radDesktopAlert1.ContentText = navn;
        radDesktopAlert1.Show();
    }
    string navn = "";
    private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string dateTime = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);

                navn = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();


                ScheduleAction(action, executionTime);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when navn is assigned as the radDesktopAlert1.ContentText, it will always be the last row in the gridview. How can I overcome this, so it will show the correct names for each callback?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Step 1: remove all those horrible try-catch blocks and ensure your program runs without them.

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, and it works fine, the problem is that navn always will be the last row in the gridview